# Error fitting the H2Oframe in R

Tags: r, time-series, deep-learning, h2o

This is my first time with deep learning using H2O Package in R. When i try to build the model, it shows error which i am unable to correct.

Here is my data

```
> head(d_1)
               x vibration_x    Speed
21892 1497340740       0.260 1224.601
21893 1497340800       0.100 1214.440
21894 1497340860       0.840 1218.984
21895 1497340920       0.125 1207.892
21896 1497340980       0.475 1206.744
21897 1497341040       0.025 1241.057
```

I am converting this dataframe to H2O type.

```
d_Hex_new <- as.h2o(d_1, destination_frame = "path_train")
> d_Hex_new
           x vibration_x    Speed
1 1497340740       0.260 1224.601
2 1497340800       0.100 1214.440
3 1497340860       0.840 1218.984
4 1497340920       0.125 1207.892
5 1497340980       0.475 1206.744
6 1497341040       0.025 1241.057

[8500 rows x 3 columns]
```

When i try to fit the model, it shows error

```
model <- h2o.deeplearning(x = Speed, y = vibration_x, data =  d_Hex_new,
                                                      validation = v_Hex_new,
                                                      activation = "Rectifier",
                                                      hidden = c(50, 50, 50),
                                                      epochs = 100,
                                                      classification = FALSE,
                                                      balance_classes = FALSE)
```

> Error in h2o.deeplearning(x = Speed, y = vibration_x, data =
>   d_Hex_new,  :    unused argument (data = d_Hex_new)

May i know Why it is not taking the H2Oframe data? 
Please help me to correct it. Thanks,D

Edited:

```
model <- h2o.deeplearning(x = Speed, y = vibration_x, training_frame =  d_Hex_new,
                          validation_frame = v_Hex_new,
                                                      activation = "Rectifier",
                                                      hidden = c(50, 50, 50),
                                                      epochs = 100,
                                                      balance_classes = FALSE)
```

> Error in is.H2OFrame(x) : object 'Speed' not found

Answer (score 1):

There is no `data` parameter in the `h2o.deeplearning` function.

Try to replace it by the parameter `training_frame`.

Also, `validation` is actually `validation_frame` and `classification` does not exist.

And `y` should be the name of your variable in between double quote and `x` a vector containing the name or the indices of the predictors variables.

The documentation:
[h2o doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/h2o.pdf)

Comment: hi, I still get the same error ` Error in is.H2OFrame(x) : object 'Speed' not found` .  . It is not taking the H2Oframe and its values.

Comment: The `y` argument takes a column name, so you must use `y = "Speed"` instead.  Also, you may find an H2O R tutorial useful if you are just starting out with H2O: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/h2o-open-tour-2016/chicago/intro-to-h2o.R